# Convolution Error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 2d, convolution

I have no idea why I don't get an identical image of 'ada.jpg' when I run the code below:

```
clear;
I = rgb2gray(imread('ada.jpg'));
figure(1)
imshow(I)
M = int8([0 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 0]);
C = convn(M, I);
figure(2)
imshow(C)
```

Here the two images:
[input image - figure (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrAim.jpg)
and
[output image - figure (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUmiL.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your input image data `I` has values between `0` and `255` and is of datatype `uint8`. After convolution, the output is a `double` and still has values between `0` and `255`.

The default for `imshow` when the input is of type `double` is to scale the color axes such that `0` is black and `1` is white. Your image is showing up almost completely as white since most of your values are `>1`.

To fix this (since you need limits of `0` to `255`) , you can specify the range of values to use as the second input to `imshow`

```
imshow(C, [0 255])
```

Or you can just provide an empty array as the second input so the colors are automatically scaled to the extrema of the input image

```
imshow(C, [])
```

As a side-note, you can use `conv2` rather than `convn` since you are simply performing 2D convolution. `conv2` requires that all inputs are floating point numbers so we first convert `M` and `I` to `double`.

```
C = conv2(double(I), double(M), 'same');
```

Alternately, you could use `imfilter` if you have the Image Processing Toolbox (as @rayryeng has suggested) and not have to worry about casting `M` and `I` as `double`

```
C = imfilter(I, M);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! But I wonder, why conv function doesn't use uint8 data type instead of double? Or is there a spesific function for this purpose?

Comment: @Burak `conv2` only accepts `double` or `single` type data.  It's mentioned in the documentation.  That's why Suever cast the data to `double`.  If you have the image processing toolbox, you can use `imfilter` which accepts nearly all types of inputs.

Comment: @rayryeng I know, read the help menu for conv function. I asked why? Is there any special reason?

Comment: @Burak It's because `conv2` typically takes the Fourier transform of the kernel and the image and performs an element-wise multiplication followed by an  inverse 2D Fourier transform. To do these operations, it needs the two to be floating point numbers. `imfilter` is a higher level function that performs these conversions for you.

Comment: @Suever Thank you!